How to send dynamic kduration without cancelling the stream flutter
loadAnimation(var kDuration) async {
    var kStartPosition =
        LatLng(traceDateList![0].latitude!, traceDateList![0].longitude!);
    var kSantoDomingo = CameraPosition(target: kStartPosition, zoom: 15);
    var kLocations = [];
    kLocations = traceDateList!;
    subscription?.cancel();
    final stream = Stream.periodic(kDuration, (count) => kLocations[count])
        .take(kLocations.length);

    print(kDuration.toString() + "Duration is");
    //Complete the future GoogleMapController

    subscription = stream.listen((location) {
      newLocationUpdate(location);
      // Uncomment the following line to pause the stream after printing 'Location 2'
      // if (location == 'Location 2') subscription!.pause();
    });
  }

How to send dynamic kduration without cancelling the stream flutter
How to send dynamic kduration without cancelling the stream flutter
How to send dynamic kduration without cancelling the stream flutter
